# Add users onto the page dynamically using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Im trying to add users onto the page dynamically using jQuery, each user has to be styled in a certain way, not sure what Im doing wrong...

```js
var user = [
{
  avatar: "http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/5899ffcf6e09a897008b5c04-1200/.jpg",
  username: "Alex",
  position: "dev",
  active: "active",
  lastLogin: 2017
}
];

function addUser(index, user) {
    var avatar = user.avatar;
    var username = user.username;
    var position = user.position;
    var active = user.active;
    var lastLogin = user.lastLogin;

    var $user = 
        "<div class='col-sm-3'>" +
        "<img class='img-circle avatar' style='width: 120px" +    
        "src='" + 
        avatar + "'" +  "/>" + 
        "<h4 style='margin-bottom: -10px;'>" + username + "</h4>" +
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -10px;'>" + position + "</h5>" +
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -7px;'>" + active + "</h5>"+
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -7px;'>" + lastLogin + "</h5>" +
        "<button style='margin-top: 20px'>Edit</button>" +
        "</div>"

    $("#col-centered").append($user);
}

$.each(user, addUser);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col-centered" class="container-fluid row">

</div>
```

any help would be appreciated!!

Comment: What seems to be the problem/question exactly?

Comment: Sorry for some reason on when running on codepen nothing shows up, not sure if its just a problem with code pen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the problem is related to the `img` that is not shown - you have missed to close the `style` attribute of your `img` - `style='width: 120px"`

```js
var user = [
{
   avatar: "http://static2.businessinsider.com/image/5899ffcf6e09a897008b5c04-1200/.jpg",
   username: "Alex",
   position: "dev",
   active: "active",
   lastLogin: 2017
}];

function addUser(index, user) {
    var avatar = user.avatar;
    var username = user.username;
    var position = user.position;
    var active = user.active;
    var lastLogin = user.lastLogin;

    var $user = 
        "<div class='col-sm-3'>" +
        "<img class='img-circle avatar' style='width: 120px'" +    
        "src='" + 
        avatar + "'" +  "/>" + 
        "<h4 style='margin-bottom: -10px;'>" + username + "</h4>" +
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -10px;'>" + position + "</h5>" +
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -7px;'>" + active + "</h5>"+
        "<h5 style='margin-bottom: -7px;'>" + lastLogin + "</h5>" +
        "<button style='margin-top: 20px'>Edit</button>" +
        "</div>"

    $("#col-centered").append($user);
}

$.each(user, addUser);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="col-centered" class="container-fluid row">

</div>
```

Comment: Hey thanks, I think im a bit confused because when I run the code snippet here it shows up, but when I have the same code in codepen nothing shows up?